# How to set decorators in zend form?

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form

I am using zend. I am trying to set decorators for the following div structure ,

```
        <div class="fm">
        <div class="fm_text">
          <div class="p_details">Debit Weight:</div>
        </div>
        <div class="fm_text">
           <div class="txtbox">
           <input type="text" name="pname" class="txtcolor"> 
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="fm_text">
          <div class="p_details">Credit Weight:</div>
        </div>
        <div class="fm_text">
       <div class="txtbox">
         <input type="text" name="pname" class="txtcolor">
        </div>   
        </div>
        </div>
<div class="fm">
......
</div>
```

It is difficult to set decorator for above div structure.I tried with following code ,

```
 public $requirednewElementDecorators = array(
        'ViewHelper',
        'Errors',
        array('Description', array('escape' => false, 'tag' => 'span', 'class' => '', 'placement' => 'prepend')),
        array(array('data' => 'HtmlTag'), array('tag' => 'div', 'class' => 'fm_text')),
        array('Label', array('tag' => 'div', 'class' => 'p_details')
        ),
        array('HtmlTag', array('tag' => 'div', 'class' => 'fm'))
    );
```

I have to use zend form so that i can validate form effectively. I can use the HTML in template and continue the flow. but i dont want to do that.Kindly help me.

Answer (score 1):

Two input-fields togehter? You can try it with a fieldset for the `<div class="fm">...</div>`. So, you must use the fieldset decorator. Why do you not want to use the `<label class="p_details">DebitWeight</label>` instead of `<div class="p_details">Debit Weight:</div>`?

This article is very helpful, maybe: http://devzone.zend.com/article/3450-Decorators-with-Zend_Form